# Is it efficient to include math operations in a for() loop ? (php)

Tags: php

I have a `for($i=X ; $i<Y ; ++$i)`

But i have two options to determine the X and Y :

1) I calculate the X and Y before the loop, using two variables

2) I include the math operations to calculate X and Y inside the for() LOOP

**Example:**

```
 for($i = ($id/100)-1) ; $i < ((($id/100)-1)*4)+($range*10)
```

But is it wise to do the option no. 2 ? Or will it perform the math operations every loop ? Should i instead just use two variables separately ? it's not very important, but why not optimizing the script as much as i can .

Thanks

Comment: The second bullet point doesn't have a valid for statement. But if you include the code in the first of the 3 segments of a for loop there won't be any difference as when you put it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` clause has three parts of which only the first is evaluated once. The other two are evaluated at every iteration (the 2nd at the start of the iteration, the 3rd at the end of the iteration).

So for those expressions it is best to have as much as possible evaluated before the `for` loop.

So this would be good:

```
$div100 = ($id/100)-1;
$end = $div100*4 + $range*10;
for ($i = $div100; $i < $end; $i++) {
    // ...
}
```

And this also:

```
$end = $e+$f*$g;
for ($i = $a+$b*$c; $i < $end; $i++) {
    // ...
}
```